# How to decide if a device can login with Webauthn's fingerprint in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, user-experience, feature-detection, webauthn

I created a Webauthn authentication for my website. 
Now I'm trying to create a good interface for the best user experience. My users are not techies.

I'm interested in the fingerprint authentication as option. The webauthn via Yubico 2 or Google Titan keys is very rare in my users. When the users log in with email and password, I want to show a message like "Do you want to register your fingerprint for your next access?  [Register now]".

I would like to show the message to the right users. 
So, how to decide in which cases show the message?

According to https://caniuse.com/#search=PublicKeyCredential, 
first of all I can use a test like this:

`var support_webauthn = (typeof window['PublicKeyCredential'] !== "undefined")`

This test determine if the browser supports the public keys authentication, but also passing the test I don't know if the hardware has a fingerprint sensor.

I know that the Android devices allows the Webauthn fingerprint authentication (instead of iPhone, for example). So, in addition of this I can check if the OS is Android 
`isAndroid = /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);`

But in this case I cannot show the message to the users with another supported device - e.g. with a Macbook pro (with the fingerprint sensor working).

How can I approach the issue?

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer:** WebAuthn will not allow you to perform such operations like probing whether Authenticator has fingerprint sensor or not in advance before credential creations.

But What you can do using [**PublicKeyCredential**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential) that allows you to detect if the user has built-in authenticator such as Windows Hello, TouchID, Android device with a fingerprint sensor (even without a fingerprint sensor, screen lock can provide equivalent user verification functionality) using the [**PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential/isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable). So this function returns a Boolean value and you can check it using JavaScript if users have built-in authenticator, if so processed and you will be able to register a user using the fingerprint sensor or screen lock or else don't prompt the user that's so simple. I personally never looked at the android but in general, this is useful to detect built-in authenticators.

***Update*** as of chrome version 77 you can make use of extensions which is provided by `PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions.extensions` object which is an optional and developers can make use of it by specifying during creation credentials extensions object and set UVM boolean to true.

```
extensions : {
    uvi: true,
    uvm: true
},
```

After credential creations, the client outputs an array of arrays with 3 values containing information about how the user was verified (e.g. fingerprint, pin, pattern) and other information. But Keep in mind in the advance developer cannot probe if a device has a fingerprint sensor or not. Please have a look at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions/extensions) for further explanation.

However, to play around webAuthn using android sample project can be found here:

https://fidoalliance.org/developer-tutorial-webauthn-web-fido2-android/
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webauthn-reauth/#0

Comment: As of March 2023 the [MDN page for PublicKeyCredential.getClientExtensionResults()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential/getClientExtensionResults) states `Warning: As of March 2019, only appId (used during creation with PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions.extensions) is supported by Chromium and Firefox does not seem to support any extension.`. In all my tests a call to getClientExtensionResults() returns an empty object, without any uvi or uvm extension informations.